# Is there a way to start an installation from a .exe file within a usb drive, and at the same time disabling the usb drive user from copying that exe?

Tags: usb, copy-protection

We have a school project on our anatomy class, and my cousin gave me this simple "BODY MASS INDEX CALCULATOR" which he created from Visual Studio. And it has an EXE file to install it. And I only want my classmates to be able to install it on their laptops, but I don't want them to copy the whole installer directory from my flashdrive including that EXE file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't : The Execute permission on a file requires the Read permission.
So in order to execute the installer, the user needs to be able to read
all the files.

Your only option is to do the installation yourself, so the USB stays
in your possession all the time.

Comment: "Your only option is to do the installation yourself, so the USB stays in your possession all the time." – Even then there may be a background task set up beforehand to copy (all) files from (any) USB.